# Calculate time from columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I would like to achieve the following:

From the DT column(source) i would like to make a new datetime row(output)  for each ST1/T1 column(source)

```
Source:
DT                       ST1 T1     ST2    T2     ST3    T3     ST4     T4
2020-08-03 12:40:00.000  0   8000   6500   1500   8001   220    8221    7000
```

This is the output i would like to achieve.

```
   **Ssd:**                  **SED**               **S**
1: 2020-08-03 12:40:00.000  2020-08-03 12:40:08.000  1
2: 2020-08-03 12:40:06.500  2020-08-03 12:40:08.000  2
3: 2020-08-03 12:40:08.001  2020-08-03 12:40:08.221  3
4: 2020-08-03 12:40:08.221  2020-08-03 12:40:15.221  4
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The DB im using is Mssql

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to use `datetime2` if you really need precision to a single millisecond.

```
select format(SSD, 'hh:mm:ss.fff'), format(SED, 'hh:mm:ss.fff'), S
from T cross apply (
    values
    ( dateadd(millisecond, ST1, DT), dateadd(millisecond,       T1, DT), 1 ),
    ( dateadd(millisecond, ST2, DT), dateadd(millisecond, ST2 + T2, DT), 2 ),
    ( dateadd(millisecond, ST3, DT), dateadd(millisecond, ST3 + T3, DT), 3 ),
    ( dateadd(millisecond, ST4, DT), dateadd(millisecond, ST4 + T4, DT), 4 )
) as pvt(SSD, SED, S);
```

The output is formatted as a string to easily verify time with milliseconds. Obviously you would normally use the raw typed value.

https://rextester.com/XDD81255

Answer (score 0):

Data/time operations are notoriously database dependent.  One method is:

```
select dt + st1 * interval '1 millisecond', dt + t1* interval '1 millisecond'
from t
union all
select dt + st2 * interval '1 millisecond', dt + t2 * interval '1 millisecond'
from t
union all
select dt + st3 * interval '1 millisecond', dt + t3 * interval '1 millisecond'
from t
union all
select dt + st4 * interval '1 millisecond', dt + t4 * interval '1 millisecond'
from t;
```

Note that this scans the table four times.  There are more efficient methods, but the best method depends on the database.